# Navigate to dynamicly created backbone path after checking checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm using `backbone.js` therefore I want to execute my router by using path. Since my path consists of ids depending on checked checkboxes I'm creating my url dynamically.
So the path looks following

```
localhost:8080/#ids/2/3/4/5
```

I'm using jquery to take those ids:

```
$('.chx:checked').map(function(){return $(this).val()}).get().join('/');
```

What should I do next to execute such generated url? maybe with backbone this should be done in a different way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope that you have your Backbone Router ([docs here](http://backbonejs.org/#Router)) set up. All you have to do is use `navigate` ([docs here](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate)), with the `trigger` option set to `true`, and it will go to your router and trigger the route that matches the route you provide.  Here is the code:

```
var ids = $('.chx:checked').map(function(){return $(this).val()}).get().join('/');
routerName.navigate("ids/" + ids, {trigger: true});
```

If you are using `Backbone.history` ([docs here](http://backbonejs.org/#History)), which you probably should be doing, then you don't need to worry about calling your specific router, you can just use

```
Backbone.history.navigate("ids/" + ids, {trigger: true});
```

You enable `Backbone.history` by calling `Backbone.history.start()` one time after your application has loaded.